# How to clear Fastlane gym output directory?

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane

I try to build my iOS app with [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/). That works so far but only for the first build.

If I try to rebuild the project I get this error message:

```
xcodebuild: error: Existing file at -resultBundlePath "xxx/output/Jenkins.result"
```

This is my Fastlane config:

```
lane :jenkins do

setup_jenkins(
   force: '1',
   unlock_keychain: '1',
   keychain_path: "~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain",
   keychain_password: "xxx",
   code_signing_identity: "xxx"
)

clean_build_artifacts
clear_derived_data

gym(
  workspace: "Travel.xcworkspace",
  configuration: "Release",
  scheme: "Jenkins",
  silent: true,
  clean: true,
  export_method: "app-store"
)

end
```

What is missing to clear the output directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [delete workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) or unix shell (`rm -f`) or windows shell (`rmdir /s /q`) command.

Comment: sometimes it is so easy :-)